# face recognition Library in python install error

Tags: python, python-import, libraries, face-recognition

I installed cmake,opencv,dlib and face_recognition
and all of them are installed succesfully without any error
when i try to import face_recognition

```
import face_recognition
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\WAJIH\Desktop\pop.py", line 1, in <module>
    import face_recognition
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

the face_recognition is installed I checked the  lib folder
i tried to type again

```
pip install face_recognition
```

i get requirements already satisfied
can anyone help and thanks

Comment: Please share some more details so we can reproduce your problem: what platform are you on, what version of Python, and how exactly you installed cmake, opencv and dlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pip uninstall face_recognition
pip install face_recognition
```

If the issue persists, you may need to try `pip install --no-cache-dir` or manually removing the module's files from your system and then reinstalling it.

Additionally, make sure that you have installed all of the required dependencies for the `face_recognition` module, such as `cmake`, `opencv`, and `dlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on windows based on the directory,

make sure that you have C++ installed because it's required for this library.

Also see : https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508